# Exploding Array of Tuple in a dataframe column in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to explode Array[(Int, Int)] column from a dataframe

INPUT:

```
colA newCol
1     [[1a, 2],[3c, 5u]]
2     [[1c, 9m], [5e, 7l]]
```

OUTPUT:

```
colA newCol
1     1a
1     3c
2     1c
2     5e
```

Comment: Please use text instead of images. You should also add what have you tried and the error, if you encountered any. For more information, read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my approach.

```
+----+--------------------+
|col1|col2                |
+----+--------------------+
|1   |[[1a, 2b], [3c, 5u]]|
|2   |[[1c, 9m], [5e, 7l]]|
+----+--------------------+
```

This is your dataframe and

```
df.withColumn("t", explode($"col2")).selectExpr("col1", "t[0]").show
```

my code results to

```
+----+----+
|col1|t[0]|
+----+----+
|   1|  1a|
|   1|  3c|
|   2|  1c|
|   2|  5e|
+----+----+
```

Comment: How can we solve it if ```t[0]```  column is of IntegerType

Comment: Let me give your desired dataframe.

Comment: Was trying something like this:

`val res =  df.withColumn("tup", explode($"newCol")).select("colA", "tup")`
`res.select(col("colA"), col("tup")("value").as("uId"))`